# Kitchen Faucet Sprayer Leak

Tags: plumbing-fixture, identify-a-tool

I hope this is the right SE site to ask this. The sprayer on my kitchen faucet has started to leak. I bought the faucet and sprayer as a combo (brand new) about two years ago. It's a unit where water is not supplied to the sprayer hose unless the faucet is on. Now, when I do turn it on, water leaks from the area where the sprayer hose enters the sprayer handle--not from the sprayer head.

So, I unscrewed the sprayer head from the hose connection, and I think the problem is this washer (or gasket) on the end of the hose. I can't find this part anywhere, and it's a tough one to google for. Hopefully, the picture will post. The washer has two concentric raised rings: one is the outside diameter, which is about 0.75". The other is at about 0.5" diameter. The whole washer is about 0.125" thick (in the direction toward you in the picture).

So, I have to find one of these mystery washers/gaskets, or spend $25 on a new sprayer. Can anyone tell me what they're called? (I've looked at the home improvement stores, and more than an hour googling and looking through ALL of Amazon.)

[image: Mystery Washer or Gasket]

Comment: Take that old gasket to any hardware store. They will have it. Those are standard sizes, not custom made.

Comment: Make and model of the faucet?

Comment: Ruskes-I haven't been able to find any with the two concentric rings. man-don't have the box anymore, and I can't remember the maker, but it was a cheap off-brand.

Comment: Can you make a pic of the inside of the sprayer, where to seal was. I am confused with the two concentric rings

Comment: Take it and the sprayer handle to a _plumbing_ store (not a big box store). They'll have a match for you in minutes.

Comment: Also remove the "where to find it" part of the question as that makes this a "shopping recommendation" question which is off-topic. "What's this called" is perfectly on-topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already suggested most home and hardware stores have a section with parts for kitchen faucets and they should have a washer that will fit your sprayer - they're pretty standard. Don't worry about the two concentric circles. Just get the right diameter and approximate thickness. The indentation on the ring might be the result of pressure from tightening the hose fitting.
The other option is to find the name of the manufacturer which is almost always embossed somewhere on the faucet. It's often on the back of the base of the faucet and you may need to read it with a small mirror held behind the faucet. Once you know the brand call their customer service. Almost all of them can identify the model with a picture and will usually send you the washer at no charge.

Comment: I appreciate your effort in trying to answer my question. But, I am capable of fixing the sprayer. My question is really about the washer (or gasket) in the picture I posted. Can't find it online, at two big-box stores, or at two local hardware stores. This confusion is probably because I was too verbose in the question, but I wanted all to know I had tried to find the answer myself. (Found a video where the guy had the exact washer. He doesn't know where to find them, either. I even read the comments--to no avail.)

Comment: Really, I've spent more time at this point than the value of a brand new complete faucet. I just can't believe I can't find those stupid washers!! Thanks, again.

Comment: Roger - I don't think anyone at SE is confused by your question. You were pretty clear. However, you may never find a washer that looks exactly like the one in the picture. We're trying to tell you that you probably don't need one exactly like that. It's doubtful that the hose/sprayer connection requires a custom washer. It's at least worth a shot to just purchase a standard rubber washer of the appropriate diameter and thickness and see if it stops the leak.

Comment: Can't believe this, but I failed (again) in my comments to you, as I did in the original question, to mention that I did try the same size flat washer and beveled washer. The first leaked a lot, the second prevented the trigger from being operated. I did take your advice and found the faucet on the company's web site, downloaded the manual, and called them for a replacement part. Operator says it comes with the 'o-ring'. Anyway, I'll accept your answer in a couple of days. (I still wish someone could tell me what they're called. Probably proprietary, anyway.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how worn your washer is and your post is quite old, but new to me since I just found it. If you have a decent digital caliper, you could measure all the dimensions and design a custom fit replacement and 3D print from TPU. I've designed and made all manner of washers and boots for the various bit and bobs of my popup camper and around the house/garage.